# Testing next.js title using next/head with jest and react-testing-library giving false positives

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have started using Next.js in my newest project and I would like to implement some tests for the pages.
I have created a `_document` file where I set up all of the meta tags which I want to use, including the title of the page.

```
<html>
<InlineStylesHead />

<body>
    <Main />
    <NextScript />

    <Head>
     <title>testing title</title>
    </Head>
</body>

</html>
```

then I set my test to render this page(which should include this `_document` as a part of it)

It's working as expected(including SSR).

So then I have tried to test it using `react-testing-library` and `jest`

here is my test:

```
it('should render the title', () => {
      render(<Page />);
      waitFor(() => {
          expect(document.title).toEqual('test title');
      });
});
```

Unfortunately, it's giving me false positives, and `expect` block is giving true no matter what.
I have also tried to set the `Head` directly on the page, unfortunately, the same issue.

Have you used any other technique to test this kind of things?
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could mock `next/head` to make it render its children:

```
jest.mock('next/head', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ children }: { children: Array<React.ReactElement> }) => {
      return <>{children}</>;
    },
  };
});
```

I got the solution from here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11060#discussioncomment-33628

Answer (score 2):

`expect` doesn't give `true`, it's just ignored in the test. `waitFor` is asynchronous due to its nature and should be awaited in order to affect test result.

It should be:

```
it('should render the title', async () => {
      ...
      await waitFor(() => {
          expect(document.title).toEqual('test title');
      });
});
```

Comment: the problem comes, that I am either getting false positives(just try to replace 'test title' with any other, it will give you false positive), or it shows:

Comment: ```received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
   Received has type:  string
   Received has value: ""```

Comment: Do you have false positives with `await waitFor`? In OP it's not really false positive, the assertion just happens outside the test (it likely would show uncaught exception if test run were long enough). I'm not sure why `received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement` can happen here. `toEqual` shouldn't cause this error, unless it was modified. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. Try https://repl.it/languages/jest

Comment: just created a repl.it test ;)

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/MassiveAnimatedProprietarysoftware#index.spec.js

Comment: hey @Estus Flask , do you mind to have another look at this `repl.it` example? :)

Comment: It doesn't show the error you mentioned, it's more meaningful, `Expected: "dsaijijdaijda" Received: ""`. It makes sense because you try to change a title in _documents but render only Page. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to test Next with react-testing-library after all. It's supposed to test real behaviour but you'll be able to test components only partially without Next-specific things . Also notice that a title in _documents is mistake, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/no-document-title.md. You likely need to test _apps instead and mock `Head` component with jest.mock.